# Linq query for replacement of word in a string

Tags: c#, .net

I need one logic using linq query in c#.

Input string :

> India is England and England is India

Output string :

> England is India and India is England

I achieved the above requirement using normal foreach loop and need logic using linq query.  Find below my foreach loop code.

```
string inputString1 = "India is England and England is India";
string[] str = inputString1.Split(' ');
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in str)
{
    if (item == "India")
    {
        sb.Append("England");
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
    else if(item == "England")
    {
        sb.Append("India");
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(item);
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: have you tried inline conditionals in `Select`? something like `str.Select(x => x == "England" ? "India" : (x == "India" ? "England" : x))`?

Comment: Simple :             string input = "India is England and England is India";
            string output = string.Join(" and ",input.Split(new string[] {" and "},StringSplitOptions.None).Reverse());

Comment: Why do you "need one logic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use 3 replaces, no need for linq:

```
var outputString1 = inputString1.Replace("India", "<placeholder>")
                    .Replace("England", "India")
                    .Replace("<placeholder>", "England");
```